# JS Variable from Form Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, variables

FYI: I have to use `data-label` as a selector for other reasons..

I need to store values from a form to use later via js, so that when a user toggles a radio button the values will be re-inserted into the form inputs.

How do I store the values, then re-insert them when the user clicks a radio button? Here's where I am at:

```
// user clicks initially, then the values would be stored..
$('[data-label="FrenchCheckbox"] [data-label="State1"] [data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Unchecked"]').click(function() {

    // want to store the initial value now!! 
    // ..then translating the form inputs to another lang
    $('[data-label="Create StepWizard"] [data-label="CreateAssetInput"]').each(function(i, ele) {
        var tString = $(ele).val();

        if(tString.length <= 0) return;

        var tSrc = 'en';
        var tDst = 'fr';
        var key = 'my api key';
        var tUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=" + key + "&source=" + tSrc + "&target=" + tDst + "&q=" + tString;
        $.get(tUrl, function(response) {
            $(ele).val(response.data.translations[0].translatedText);
        });
    });
});
```

Then when the user clicks the radio button (first line below) reinsert the initial values into the form fields?

```
$('[data-label="LanguageRadioButtons"] [data-label="French"] [data-label="Radio Button"] [data-label="Initial"] ').click(function() {

    // how do I reinsert the values from the initial input?

});
```

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: What's wrong with a simple javascript object?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, I am just looking for a solution that works. I am not very experienced in js / jquery, so do not know how to structure my code to accomplish what I am aiming to do. If you could give me an example I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to store the defaults on each element using  jQuery `data()`

```
// want to store the initial value now!! 
$(this).data('default', $(this).val());
```

Then to reset:

```
 /* within event handler */
 $(this).val( $(this).data('default') );
```

**[data() docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @charlietfl. Can you help me figure out how to integrate this into my example above? I am not very experienced with js / jquery. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what behavior you want since you are using 2 click handlers for the elements.